# How to disable Add Dependency in Generate menu

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I configure one project in Spring and later I open new Project in Maven and when I press Alt+Insert, I have new options like *Add Dependency...*. It's very inconvenient. How to disable this?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4n3V.png)

Comment: How is this inconvenient?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a regression bug in IntelliJ 2023.1 and will be fixed with 2023.1.1 and 2023.2, see [IDEA-314227](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-314227). Once these versions have been released, consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's close to impossible. Because the generate menu is actually a basic plugin of intellij. So you may need to develop a plugin to remove it.